# NO_LCP Page speed insights and lighthouse

Tags: lighthouse, google-pagespeed

Lighthouse log:
PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT

```
Channel: DevTools
Initial URL: https://dev.workscope.com/
Chrome Version: 99.0.4844.74
Stack Trace: LHError: PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT
    at devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools-frontend/front_end/third_party/lighthouse/lighthouse-dt-bundle.js:146:58
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Driver$1.sendCommandToSession (devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools-frontend/front_end/third_party/lighthouse/lighthouse-dt-bundle.js:146:10)
    at Driver$1.sendCommand (devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools-frontend/front_end/third_party/lighthouse/lighthouse-dt-bundle.js:146:257)
    at Object.clearBrowserCaches (devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools-frontend/front_end/third_party/lighthouse/lighthouse-dt-bundle.js:164:899)
    at resetStorageForNavigation (devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools-frontend/front_end/third_party/lighthouse/lighthouse-dt-bundle.js:166:447)
    at async Object.prepareTargetForIndividualNavigation (devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools-frontend/front_end/third_party/lighthouse/lighthouse-dt-bundle.js:168:161)
    at async Function.runPass (devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools-frontend/front_end/third_party/lighthouse/lighthouse-dt-bundle.js:214:918)
    at async Function.run (devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools-frontend/front_end/third_party/lighthouse/lighthouse-dt-bundle.js:214:129)
    at async Function._gatherArtifactsFromBrowser (devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools-frontend/front_end/third_party/lighthouse/lighthouse-dt-bundle.js:363:456)
```

Pagespeed insights
https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.workscope.com%2F

I tried to find information about, but dont find exactly answers, maybe you know?

Answer (score 0):

When testing a [basic canvas element demo from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#examples) , Lighthouse said:

> Something went wrong with recording the trace over your page load.
> Please run Lighthouse again. (NO_LCP)

According to this [github post](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/12456#issuecomment-835411522) the cause was a result of there not being any other content within the html body element, other than the canvas itself.

An h1 before the canvas element and a paragraph after it, returned standard performance results in Lighthouse.

Nothing in body other than canvas element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>Canvas API - basic_example - code sample</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<style>
body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script>
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 100);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Lighthouse said:

> Please run Lighthouse again. (NO_LCP)

---

After adding other html content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>Canvas API - basic_example - code sample</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<style>
body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Some text in H1</h1>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur..</p>

<script>
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 100);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Lighthouse said:

> 100 Performance